# Результат выполнения net view

Tags: windows-7, c++

Ребята (у кого windows 7 стоит), запустите у себя комaнду `net view` в командной строке и пришлите скриншот результата. Мне результат парсить надо в с++, а есть сомнения, что в XP он другой (а программу на кластере на семерках буду запускать).

Answer (score 1):

```
Имя сервера            Заметки

-------------------------------------------------------------------------------
\\MICROSOF-CA3FA9                                                              
\\MICROSOF-CC1B34                                                              
\\PROGRAMMER                                                                   
Команда выполнена успешно.
```

Ну вот так вот приходит.

Comment: это в win7 получилось? и между именем сервера заметки и черточками одна строка?

Comment: Да,  win7. ровно так как написано

Answer (score 1):

```
Имя сервера            Заметки

-----------------------------------
\\ИМЯ-ПК
Команда выполнена успешно.
```

Ничего почти не выводит.

Answer (score 0):

```
Системная ошибка 6118.

Недоступен список серверов для этой рабочей группы.

c:/users/avp $
```

Comment: Обратите внимание ! Вывод в **stderr** (дескриптор 2)